# Spark, grep / search in very long strings / datablock

Tags: apache-spark

I have a very long string / datablock where I want to search / grep within.

Example: `...AAABBAAAAVAACCDE...`

In this example, I want to search for AVA.

The length of the string is hundredth of GBs

My problem is, when I split the string in block of xxMB (to allow parallel execution) the search will fail on the boundaries.

Example

```
 [Block 1] ...AAABBAAAA 
 [Block 2] VAACCDE...
```

In the example above, I will never find the string AVA.

Are the methods or helper function to address this boundary problem?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

In Spark it's not each to read these custom formats, especially files that are not delimted by newlines, very efficiently out-of-the box.

In essence you need a FileInputStream from your original file (the one with the huge string) and for each chunk you want each record to be read this as a stream

You can, for example, retain a cache of the last *`n`* characters from each chuck/record and concat that to the next record, effectively creating an overlap.

eg:

```scala
val fileIn = "hugeString.txt"
val fileOut = "sparkFriendlyOutput.txt"
val reader = new FileInputStream(fileIn)
val writer = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fileOut))

val recordSize = 9
val maxSearchLength = 3

val bytes = Array.fill[Byte](recordSize)(0)
val prefix = Array.fill[Byte](maxSearchLength)(' ')

Stream
  .continually((reader.read(bytes),bytes))
  .takeWhile(_._1 != -1)
  .foreach{
    case (_, buffer) =>   {
      writer.write(prefix ++ buffer :+ '\n'.toByte)
      Array.copy(buffer.toList.takeRight(maxSearchLength).toArray,0,prefix,0,maxSearchLength)
    }}

writer.close()
```

reader.close()

This turns this string

> 1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345...

Into this File:

> 123456789
>
> 789012345678
>
> 678901234567
>
> 567890123456
>
> ...

This does require you to pick a maximum length that you ever want to search for, because that's what the overlap is for.

This file could be read in Spark very easily

On the other hand if you don't have the luxury to be able to store this on disk (or in memory) perhaps you could look into creating a custom spark streaming solution where you either implement a custom streaming source (structured streaming) or custom receiver (Dstream) that reads the file via a similar FileInputStream + buffered prefix solution.

PS. You could do smarter things with the overlap (at least divide by two, so noth the entire possible length is duplicated,

PS I assumed that you don't care about the absolute position. If you do, then I would store the original offset as Long next to each line

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will try to implement your solution

Comment: @Yves did it work? If so, can you please accept this answer?